# jQuery heightStyle option not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to set the heightStyle of my tabs to 'auto', as described by the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-heightStyle), but it doesn't seem to be working.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ndyy8/9/

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>one</p>
        <p>one</p>
        <p>one</p>
        <p>one</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>two</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>three</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Also, I was trying to get the active tab later on in my code by calling `$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');`. However, this returns the outer tab container `<div id="tab"></div>` rather than the active inner tab div.

I'm basically just following the documentation examples without trying to do anything complicated, did something happen with the newest jQuery ui update that broke some of the basic functionality of things like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong version of JQuery and JQuery-UI.

If you switch your fiddle to `JQuery 1.8.2` and include:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

in the HTML portion, then it works fine.

Documentation [examples](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#entry-examples) cover this.

New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kpqbq/) showing this.